# Java get Bounds of a Column TableHeader

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jtableheader

I need to get the rectangle of a single column in the Table Header. Is there a way to receive this information?

Comment: Initially you need to try something, iterate it over and over. If stuck somewhere you need to post relevant code on SO and explain what exactly you need.

Comment: `JTable#getColumnModel#getColumn(int)`

Comment: *"I need to get the rectangle of a single Column in the Table Header."*  Why?

Comment: You might be able to use a [JTableHeader#getHeaderRect(int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/table/JTableHeader.html#getHeaderRect-int-)

Answer (score 1):

i hope you want to know the size of a cell from a table header?

to get the height of the the cell you must ask the tableheader for size and take its height

```
JTable table;
int height = table.getTableHeader().getSize().height //JTable header is a JComponent
```

to get the width of a cell you have to take the width from the tableColumnModel

```
int column; //the index of desired column
int width = table.getTableColumnModel().getColumn(column).getWidth(); //as mentioned by @MadProgrammer
```

as desired i add the hints on how to get the location

```
int xRel = table.getTableHeader().getX();
int column; //the index of desired column
for (int c = 0; c < column; c++){
    //adding all cell withds to come to your column
    x = x + table.getTableColumnModel().getColumn(c).getWidth();
} 

int yRel = table.getTableHeader().getY();
```

to get to the absolut coordinates you have to ask your frame, where it is and then add the relative coordinates

```
JFrame frame; //your frame
int xAbs = frame.getLocation().x + xRel;
int yAbs = frame.getLocation().y + yRel;
```

Comment: I also need the Position of the Table Header

Comment: relativ to parent JComponent or absolut on screen? @dbausnnd